# Retrieving filesize for the collection of these IDataOrganizationNode

Tags: java, file, tomcat7, filesize

I would like to get the size of ingested files in [KITDM](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base) (on tomcat7) I can iterate over like this:

```
ICollectionNode root = pContainer.getFileTree().getRootNode();
IDataOrganizationNode dataSubTree = Util.getNodeByName(root, Constants.STAGING_DATA_FOLDER_NAME);//Constant is "data"
ICollectionNode coll = (ICollectionNode) dataSubTree;
for (IDataOrganizationNode n : coll.getChildren()) {
    System.out.print( n.getName() + ": "
      + n.getAttributes().toString()
      + " ("
      + n.getTransientNodeId().getDigitalObjectId().getStringRepresentation()
      + ")"
      + "; " );
}
```

On local storage I can easily use

```
File path = new File( stringForPath );
```

and then access properties with `isDirectory()`, `length` etc. to accumulate the actual size of some files.

But how do I get from the IDataOrganizationNode to the File? Please also explain how you got to you idea/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `pContainer.getDestination()` gives me the "base" `URL` of all the nodes I would iterate over, I just went on that one, dropped the prefix "file:" from the resulting String and replaces multiple slashes with just a single leading one. This works on GNU/Linux so far, for other Systems I'd need to see the resulting URL.

The `URL.toString()` then is strangled to a `File` by this:

```
public static File getFileFromURLOrFileString( String fn ) {
    File f = new File( fn );
    URI u = null;
    int i = 0;
    if ( ! f.exists() ) {
        while ( fn.indexOf("file:") >= 0 ) {
            i = fn.indexOf("file:");
            System.out.println( " n: " + fn + " – " + i + " – " + ( (i >= 0) ? fn.substring(i) : "" ) );
            if ( i == 0 ) {
                fn = fn.replaceFirst("file:","");
            } else {
                fn = fn.substring(i);
            }
        }
        while ( fn.indexOf("//") >= 0 ) {
            fn = fn.replaceAll("//","/");
        }
        //System.out.println( " n: " + fn + " – " + fn.indexOf("//") );
        u = (new File( fn )).toURI();
        f = new File( u );
    }
    return f;
}
```

And finally I can walk through the File and possible subdirectories to accumulate their size:

```
private static boolean isLink( File f ) {
    Path p = Paths.get( f.toString() );
    return Files.isSymbolicLink( p );
}
private static long usedSpace( File path ) //throws FileExistsException
{
    long size = 0l;
    if ( path == null ) {
        System.out.println( "ERROR: No Files in " + path );
        System.out.println("exists   :" + path.exists() );
        System.out.println("isDir    :" + path.isDirectory() );
        System.out.println("isFile   :" + path.isFile() );
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if ( isLink( path ) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    int c = 0;
    try {
        c = path.listFiles().length;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "path : " + path );
        System.out.println( "link : " + isLink( path ) );
        System.out.println( "file : " + path.isFile() );
        System.out.println( "dir  : " + path.isDirectory() );
        System.out.println( "list : " + path.listFiles() );
        System.out.println( "count: " + c );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( c == 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }
    for ( File file : path.listFiles()) {
        if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
            size += usedSpace(file);
        } else {
            try {
                if ( isLink( file ) ) {
                    //+=0
                } else {//file.isFile() …
                //} else if(Files.isRegularFile(link)) {// had e.g. sockets and a pipe
                    //                System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
                    size += file.length();
                }
            } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println( file.toString()
                        + "\t" + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }

    }
    return size;
}
```

Probably there are much nicer ways to do this, but at least it gives me the filesize of my ingest (upload).